# Implementing search feature in Laravel MySQL with InnoDb

Tags: php, search, laravel-4

I am trying to implement a search that searches across multiple tables. Here's the scenario:

Consider the database structure:
Many to many: Images table and Subject table.
Many to many: Images table and Style table

The end result that I want is an Collection of certain eloquent model say `'images'`. Now I am to look for a keyword in two tables (Models) say `'subject'` and `'style'`.

Now I need final result where `$result=subject->images()+style->images()+Image::where(query)`. The `$result` variable must be of type collection object of `'images'` model.
This is what I tried:

```
$subject=Subject::where('subject','=',$searchParam)->get();
$results=Image::where('type','!=','profile_picture');    
$style = Style::where('style', '=', $searchParam)->get();
            $results=$results->filter(function($result){
            $boolVal=false;
            if(in_array($result->styles()->style,$style) or in_array($result->subjects()->subject,$subject))
            {
                $boolVal=true;
            }
            return $boolVal;
        });
```

Also there's another approach which I don't know how to implement. i.e. 
Get `$subject` and `$style` array as shown in code above, somehow merge the `$subject->images()`,`$style->images()`and `Image::where(query)` while eliminating redundant entries.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is same as my answer to other question. Here's the link:
[Merge collections in laravel from relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666726/merge-collections-in-laravel-from-relations)