# Merge collections in laravel from relations

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Suppose I have 3 tables.

1. Images
2. Subject
3. Style

The relationship is Many to Many(Images,Subject) and Many to Many(Images,Style).
Now I want to do something like:

`$result=$subjectResult->images()->merge($styleResult->images())`.
I want the type of result to be an Images Collection Object.

So far I've tried it as:

```
$subjectResult=Subject::with('images')->where(query)->get();
```

But this returns the subject rows,Image rows and the pivot rows. I want to extract the Images collection from it.

Image Model:

```
public function styles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Style','style_images','image_id','keyword_id');
}
public function subjects(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Subject','subject_images','image_id','subject_id');
}
```

**The ultimate objective is to get Image collection merged from results of query on subject and style.**

Comment: I think the problem is in attempting to access images relation from a `Collection`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here's what worked for me. Using `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` worked for me. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
$results=Image::whereHas('subjects',function($q) use ($searchParam){
            $q->where('subject','LIKE','%'.$searchParam.'%');
        })->orWhereHas('styles',function($q) use ($searchParam){
            $q->where('style','LIKE','%'.$searchParam.'%');
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Image::has('styles')->orHas('subjects')->get();
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can get collection of images from subject and style separately and merge them into one single Collection
Code is something like that

```
$images = new Collection();
$images = $images->merge($subject->images);
$images= $images->merge($style->images);
```

Comment: I get the following error:`Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$images`  I have also edited my question to show the Image model

Comment: To use construction I recommended you can make sure Subject model has method images() and get the exact $subject with fir example $subject=Subject::find(1)

Comment: In this case you already have a collection and can merge it straight with the other collection.

Comment: The thing is I wanted to merge the rows of images table based on the results of these two and images method or property can't be used on Collection object. Anyway thanks for the effort.